# Does the Connection Between Gibbs and Clausius Entropy Require Quantum Mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, entropy

**Context**

My question arises from my attempts to rationalize some of the more unintuitive equations from thermodynamics to my physical chemistry students. Namely, I want to establish a rational connection between the Gibbs definition of entropy on the microscopic scale and the Clausius definition of entropy, which only depends on the macroscopic reversible heat transfer and the temperature. The only way I could figure to make this connection was to appeal to the quantum mechanical [adiabatic theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adiabatic_theorem) by Born. As you can see from my derivation below, I am also tacitly assuming a canonical ensemble since I utilize the Boltzmann distribution for the microstate probabilities. Does anyone know of a different or potentially better way of making this connection explicit? I am particularly concerned that this derivation relies explicitly on the energy levels being quantized, as this even shows up in my formulation of the Boltzmann probabilities.

**Derivation I shared with my students**

First, we will begin with the Gibbs entropy.  for system with several microstates $j$,
\begin{align*}
S &= - k_B \sum_j p_j \ln(p_j) \\
\implies dS &= - k_B \sum_j d\left[ p_j \ln (p_j) \right] \\
&= - k_B \sum_j dp_j \ln(p_j) - k_B \sum_j \left( \frac{p_j}{p_j} \right) dp_j \\ 
&= - k_B \sum_j dp_j \ln(p_j) - k_B \sum_j dp_j \\ 
&= - k_B \sum_j dp_j \ln(p_j)
\end{align*}
where we cleaned up the expression by using the fact that the sum of the changes of the probabilities $dp_j$ is equal to 0 (conservation of probability). We can now use the Boltzmann factor for each of the values of $p_j$ (no degeneracy factor is needed for the microstates),
\begin{align*}
dS &= - k_B \sum_j \ln(p_j) dp_j \\
&= - k_B \sum_j \ln \left( \frac{1}{Z} e^{-\frac{E_j}{k_BT}} \right)  dp_j \\
&=- k_B \sum_j \left[- \ln(Z) - \frac{E_j}{k_BT} \right] dp_j  \\
&= \frac{1}{T} \sum_j E_j dp_j
\end{align*}
where we once again used the conservation of probability to eliminate the sum including $Z$. Some of the consequences of the  quantum-mechanical adiabatic theorem are,
\begin{align*}
\delta w_{rev} &= \sum_j p_j dE_j \\
\implies \delta q_{rev} &= \sum_j E_j dp_j 
\end{align*}
Then we can identify the sum trailing $\frac{1}{T}$ as the reversible heat transferred during a process in which we are always at equilibrium,
\begin{gather*}
 dS = \frac{\delta q_{rev}}{T} 
\end{gather*}
Note that the entropy is only equivalent to the reversible heat. This is actually the definition of entropy according to Clausius. Most textbooks very cryptically assert that this is the definition of entropy and then proceed to use it constantly to explore the laws of thermodynamics.

Comment: I think the confusion may be conflating the microstates, rooted in discrete degrees of freedom of motion of classical gas particles, with quantized energy levels in the QM sense. Gibbs and Boltzmann worked out their definitions of entropy well before QM was developed.

Comment: I’m not sure I follow: in my entire education the Boltzmann distribution and entropy are related directly to quantum states. But obviously you’re right that these ideas pre-date quantum. What sort of arguments were made instead?